# Two instances of an application connected with two schemas of same postgres database is unable to differentiate

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube, multi-tenant, gerrit, saas

I am working on a **SaaS** solution currently provisioning **sonarqube and gerrit** applications on kubernetes.

As part of that I want to create a new schema in my postgres database for every new application that I provision. Application is connecting using following connection string, (i.e., instance1, instance2, instance3... and so on)

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/gerrit?user=instance1&password=instance1&currentSchema=instance1
```

The solution works fine for the first occurrence of provisioning gerrit and sonarqube by creating associated tables in the new schema. However, it fails on second time with another new schema in the same database, these failures are most likely associated with application trying to create the associated tables but it **already exists**.

I am creating the schema with following sql.

```
create user instance1 with login password 'instance1';
CREATE SCHEMA instance1 AUTHORIZATION instance1;
ALTER ROLE instance1 SET search_path=instance1;


create user instance2 with login password 'instance2';
CREATE SCHEMA instance2 AUTHORIZATION instance2;
ALTER ROLE instance2 SET search_path=instance2;
```

I am having difficulty in understanding this behavior, how can two separate applications configured against two different schemas of same database could see each others tables.

In order to reproduce this problem I quickly wrote a python script to connect to two different schemas of same database and create the same table and it works fine.

```
import psycopg2
import sys
import random

_user = raw_input("user: ")
con = None

try:

   con = psycopg2.connect(database='gerrit', user=_user,
                           password=_user, host='localhost')
   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute('SELECT version()')
   ver = cur.fetchone()
   print ver
   table_name = 'tbl_%d' %(1)#random.randint(1,100))
   cur.execute('CREATE TABLE %s (id serial, name varchar(32));' %(table_name))
   cur.execute('INSERT INTO %s values (1, \'%s\');' %(table_name, table_name+_user))
   con.commit()
   cur.execute('SELECT * from %s' %(table_name))
   ver = cur.fetchone()
   print ver
except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
   print 'Error %s' % e
   sys.exit(1)
finally:
   if con:
       con.close()
```

Output as follows

```
$ python pg_test_connect.py
user: instance1
(1, 'tbl_1instance1')

$ python pg_test_connect.py
user: instance2
(1, 'tbl_1instance2')
```

Since I am able to verify this workflow from python, is this the limitation from **JDBC** or the applications(gerrit & sonarqube), Has anyone came across this problem with postgres?

Comment: At the postgres side you canincrease the logging (log all statements) to see what these crippled ORMs try to do. Also: I would add pg_catalog to the search_paths. (and maybe even public)

Answer (score 1):

The default search_path is "$user", public. Where $user will be substituted with the value of SESSION_USER, so there is no need to explicitly specify the search_path for the ROLE.
But the caveat is that the user has to have USAGE permission to any schema within the search path. If the "$user" schema does not exist it will be ignored. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-client.html).

Answer (score 1):

So, after tinkering gerrit source code I figured out that its not honoring the currentSchema option. That more or less explains why it has been behaving this way.